# Nested Queries using meta_query

Tags: meta-query

I'm trying to build a query that lists posts of a custom type with specific custom field values. Then I need to list children of each of those posts within the post, and those children also need to be filtered by specific custom field values.

Here's my current code, which isn't working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'clients-placements',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'type',
                'value' => 'Client'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'featured',
                'value' => 'yes'

            )
        )                       
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    ?>

    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'clients' );?>

    <ul id="placements">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'clients-placements',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'type',
                    'value' => 'Placement',
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'featured',
                    'value' => 'yes',

                )
            )   
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

        // The Loop
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
            echo '<li>';
            the_title();
            the_content();
            echo '</li>';
        endwhile;


    ?>
</ul>   
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inner query is overwriting the outer, you've assigned both to `$the_query`.

Comment: yup just change the second $the_query to $child_query and u are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Just change this:

```
  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
```

To this:

```
  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

---

Just to explain a bit more if this is the only loop you got in that page you can do it even simpler like this (without using '$the_query' at all..

Example:

```
<?php 
    query_posts(array( 
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'showposts' => 10 
    ) );  
?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
//Here would be the content you want to loop...
```

Comment: if you create a new `WP_Query` object, you have to call `the_post()` in that object to set up global variables properly, otherwise you're referring to an entirely different query object.

Comment: i guess that depends if we are talking about a post or say a category... but i do get what you say :) - i didnt use WP_Query becuse this guy want a list of posts and not one post.. wouldnt this work?? --> this works great on my theme..